# How to display data from server in textarea

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have below code in C# which adds data in Dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ReadFile()
{
        Dictionary<int, string> datalist = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\temp\\Sample.txt");
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            datalist.Add(i, line);
            i++;
        }
        return datalist;
}
```

Now, I want to display Dictionary data separated by key line by line in textarea. Below is my UI code

```
<button type="button" id ="GetFlatFile">Click Me!</button>

<div id ="DisplayFlatFile">

</div>

function GetFlatFileAndSetupColumn() {
        $("#GetFlatFile").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/ReadFile",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (jsondata) {
                    mydata = jsondata.d;
                    $('#DisplayFlatFile').empty();
                    $('#DisplayFlatFile').append(mydata);
                }, error: function (x, e) {
                    alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

How to do it?

Comment: Are you sure `jsondata.d` contains key values? If you want to use line break for every keys, use `$.each()` and put `<br />` before continuing to the next key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `GetFlatFile` is not a `<textarea>` element, it's `<div>` element. Assumed that `jsondata.d` contains dictionary values returned from code-behind method, you can use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate values:

```
function GetFlatFileAndSetupColumn() {
    $("#GetFlatFile").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ReadFile",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (jsondata) {
                mydata = jsondata.d;
                $('#DisplayFlatFile').empty();

                // iterate keys and values here
                $(mydata).each(function (key, value) {

                    // data display example
                    $('#DisplayFlatFile').append(key + ' - ' + value);

                    // line break per iteration
                    $('#DisplayFlatFile').append('<br />');

                });
            }, error: function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Additionally, your code-behind method should be marked with `[WebMethod]` attribute :

```
[WebMethod]
public static Dictionary<int, string> ReadFile()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> datalist = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\temp\\Sample.txt");
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        datalist.Add(i, line);
        i++;
    }
    return datalist;
}
```

Related issue:

[How to get data from C# WebMethod as Dictionary<> and display response using jquery ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162420/how-to-get-data-from-c-sharp-webmethod-as-dictionary-and-display-response-usin)

Comment: Could you please explain the line `mydata = jsondata.d;`? What is `d` property?

Comment: `d` property contains array of objects contained inside `Dictionary` passed from server. You can see the example [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/96/handling-json-arrays-returned-from-asp-net-web-services-with-jquery).